# Azure SQL Management instance - restore db different version

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

Actually we have Azure SQL Management instance I got a backup but I cannot restore our VM SQL Server owing this has a SQL Server version less SQL Azure (Azure Team updated SQL Server a couples week ago), so We cannot update QA Server to last SQL Server Version and we need to recovery the backup a soon a possible.

Do you know any way to recover this backup from SQL Azure to this server getting a less version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use bcp to export the data from Azure SQL Database and then use bcp again or Import/Export Wizard or SSIS to import the data on the SQL Server VM.

You can use Azure Data Factory (ADF) to export tables to your SQL Server VM. ADF will create those tables and copy the data.